# Force the end of a LaTeX command in MultiMarkDown

Tags: latex

I'm using [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) to generate a LaTeX file of an academic paper I'm working on. I'm using biblatex for the bibliography, which allows for commands like `autocite` and `autocites`:

```
This is a true statement.\autocite{source:2007}
```

When `autocites` is used, each braced entry is considered a citation source, which works great when there are multiple sources for the citation:

```
This is another statement.\autocites{othersource}{yetanothersource}
```

However, when the text following the `autocites` command is another bracketed LaTeX command, biblatex treats it as another source, spacing:

```
This is another statement.\autocites{othersource}{yetanothersource} {\itshape The New York Times}…
```

results in a footnote that looks like this:

```
Bib data for othersource; bib data for yetanothersource; \itshape The New York Times
```

That's a problem. One obvious way around it is to use a different command for italics, like `\emph{The New York Times}`, but unfortunately MultiMarkdown uses `itshape` instead of `\emph`, and I'd rather not muck around in MMD's source code.

Is there a LaTeX sequence or code that will force a break between the two sequences of braced commands? Forcing a line break with `\\` kind of works (`{yetanothersource}\\{\itshape`), but it creates a new paragraph after the first command. Is there something similar to `\\` that will tell the LaTex engine to begin parsing the `{itshape}` as a new command rather than as part of `autocite{}`?

Comment: Would a `\ ` in between the braces force a break?

Comment: Nope. a `\` escapes the following `{`, causing the brace to actually output…

Comment: So it doesn't end up escaping the following space? I suppose you could try `\~` instead if that's the case.

Comment: I tried using bibtex with multimarkdown for a while, and eventually just gave up. It didn't work well for me.

Comment: There we go. A slash between spaces doesn't work, but when placed immediately after the final brace, it works: `\autocites{blah}{blah}\ {\itshape blah}`

Comment: And the answer is in a comment :) What do we do with this?

Comment: Since the slash right after your command works, how about a full stop instead of a slash? If `autocite` is used in the `footnote` mode what it does, is it usually 'moves' the fullstop. So I guess `... another statement \autocites{blah}{blah}. {\itshape blah}` might work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hopeless guess, but have you tried `\relax`?

Something like:

```
This is another statement.\autocites{othersource}{yetanothersource}\relax {\itshape The New York Times}…
```

Comment: I imagine that the "\" solution was actually "\ " (inserting a space).
It's certainly more compact, though I believe that \relax is the "official" TeX way of saying "Don't do anything".